# Creating a popoverview with only custom viewcontroller class on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to implement a `popovercontroller` on the iPhone that has a modal presentation similar to the iPad. I am only able to get UI to generate when using storyboard and I would much prefer to build a controller fully programmatically. All the demos on SO and google seem to use storyboard. I can see methods from my custom `UIViewController` printing to the logs, but nothing appears on the modal popover. [Showing Popover view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x94Eo.png)

```
    func handlePop(sender: UIButton) {

      //let popController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "unique") as UIViewController //only way I generate UI in popoverview

      let popController = MyCustomViewController()  //would like to use

     //positioning 
    let placementView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(placementView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: placementView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-64-[v0(200)]", views: placementView)

    popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    if let poppingVC = popController.popoverPresentationController {


        let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = poppingVC

        popover.sourceView = placementView
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: -100, width: 0, height: 100)

        popover.delegate = self

        self.present(popController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

}

func dismissView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

What am I missing that is keeping the `popovercontroller` blank?

```
    class RegionSelectionController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



let mainLabel = UILabel()
let cellId = "cellId"
let footerId = "footerId"
var keys = [String]()

let tableView = UITableView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self



    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.register(RegionFilterCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    tableView.delegate = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(keys.count)
    return keys.count

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! RegionFilterCell

    let regionName = keys[indexPath.row]
    cell.regionLabel.text = regionName

    return cell

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerCell = RegionRequestNewLocationCell()


    return footerCell
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row, keys[indexPath.row])
}




override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    ref.child("Region").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snap) in
        if snap.exists() {

            let key: String = snap.key as String
            self.keys.append(key)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async ( execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })


}
```

}

```
  class RegionFilterCell: BaseTableCell {

let regionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Medium", size: 16)
    label.text = "UMD"
    return label
}()

let separatorBar: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(151, green: 151, blue: 151, alpha: 0.3)
    return view
}()
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(regionLabel)
    addSubview(separatorBar)
    //addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(100)]", views: regionLabel)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: regionLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: regionLabel)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: separatorBar)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(0.5)]|", views: separatorBar)
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try setting the content size? `popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 275, height: 225)`. Obviously you'd want to change the h/w values for whatever you need

Comment: Adding `popController.preferredContentSize` only changes the sizing of the popController..are you saying I need to make sure the frame of the controller is the same as `preferredContentSize`? Still seeing the same blurred popview. Yeah, I see what you are saying about the optional unwrapping, but is that preventing my controller from showing?

Comment: No, sorry I deleted that comment because it really wasn't relevant to your problem. I honestly can't see what you're problem is. Have you tried changing the arrow direction to `.any`?

Comment: I just know from experience that sometimes when I have it set to like `.up`, and there isn't enough space below the source view, it won't even show. I don't know if that pertains to your situation or not.

Comment: I just edited my post showing the image of the popover that I see in my simulator, which is why I am so confused. It is showing up, but completely blank unless the `popController` comes from the storyboard

Comment: Ohhh okay Josh I get what the problem is. Was this VC created using a Storyboard?

Comment: No, I created it only programmatically

Comment: Would you show some of the code for your `MyCustomViewController` class? I'm thinking that it's a problem with the layout over there, not with you're presentation controller

Comment: Just updated the post to show the code.

Comment: You never set the frame for your tableView in your VC that you're showing. You're adding it to the view but you're not laying out anything else, hence nothing is showing. Also in your code above you instantiate something called `MyCustomViewController`, but the VC you just showed code for has a different name.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer for resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're showing, you're never setting the frame for your content in the ViewController that's being presented (in this case your `UITableView`). If you don't set the frame for the view, it won't be shown on the screen. You need to either specify the origin and size using a `CGRect`, or use auto layout with `NSLayoutConstraints`. The easiest way is just a frame. So in `viewDidLoad`, say you wanted to have the tableView take up the whole view:

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
```

Also you need to make sure you're instantiating the right VC. I don't know if you just used the name `MyCustomViewController` for the purpose of the example, but the VC you showed in your code is named `RegionSelectionController`